# React-native - MapViewDirections not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-native

I'm trying to use MapViewDirections on google map to provide directions but it's not showing up on the map. Any ideas?

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
     {.....}
    coordinates: [
      {
      latitude: 37.3317876,
      longitude: -122.0054812,
    },
    {
      latitude: 37.771707,
      longitude: -122.4053769,
<MapView 
  style={styles.map}
  region ={{
    latitude:this.state.latitude,
    longitude:this.state.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.1,
    longitudeDelta: 0.1,
  }}
>
  <MapViewDirections
    origin={this.state.coordinates[0]}
    destination={this.state.coordinates[1]}
    apikey={apikey}
    strokeWidth={3}
    strokeColor="hotpink"
  />
</MapView>
```

Comment: where are you setting the coordinates in state. please post more code

Comment: @Shivam In the constructor. I added it to OP

Comment: make sure you are using the correct api key for the respective platform

Comment: check your this.state.latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It working for me.
You have to use google direction API to get all possible location points between origin and destination.

once you get all points, you can use polygons to connects that points, it will draw route between your origin and destination.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';


const mode = 'driving'; // 'walking';
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;
const SPACE = 0.01;
const DEFAULT_PADDING = { top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100 };
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.mapRef = null;    
  }

  state = {    
    MARKERS : null,
    origin :'22.9962,72.5996',
    destination :'23.0134,72.5624',    
    destMarker : '',
    startMarker :'',
    imageloaded:false,
  }

  componentWillMount()
  {
    this.getRoutePoints(this.state.origin,this.state.destination);
  }

  /**
   * This method will give you JSON response with all location points between 2 location
   */
  getRoutePoints(origin,destination) {
    console.log("-----getRoutePoints-----")    
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${origin}&destination=${destination}&key=YOUR API KEY&mode=${mode}`;
    console.log("URL -- >>" + url);

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson.routes.length) {
          var cortemp = this.decode(responseJson.routes[0].overview_polyline.points) // definition below;
          var length = cortemp.length - 1;

          var tempMARKERS = []; 
          tempMARKERS.push(cortemp[0]) ;   //start origin        
          tempMARKERS.push(cortemp[length]); //only destination adding

          console.log("tempMARKERS : " + JSON.stringify(tempMARKERS));

          this.setState({
            coords: cortemp,            
            MARKERS:tempMARKERS,
            destMarker : cortemp[length],
            startMarker:cortemp[0],
          });

        }
      }).catch(e => { console.warn(e) });
  }

  /**
   * This method will transforms something like this geocFltrhVvDsEtA}ApSsVrDaEvAcBSYOS_@... to an array of coordinates
   */

  decode(t, e) {
    for (var n, o, u = 0, l = 0, r = 0, d = [], h = 0, i = 0, a = null, c = Math.pow(10, e || 5); u < t.length;) {
      a = null, h = 0, i = 0;
      do a = t.charCodeAt(u++) - 63, i |= (31 & a) << h, h += 5; while (a >= 32);
      n = 1 & i ? ~(i >> 1) : i >> 1, h = i = 0;
      do a = t.charCodeAt(u++) - 63, i |= (31 & a) << h, h += 5; while (a >= 32);
      o = 1 & i ? ~(i >> 1) : i >> 1, l += n, r += o, d.push([l / c, r / c])
    }
    return d = d.map(function (t) {
      return {
        latitude: t[0],
        longitude: t[1]
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * After loading custome image of marker it will render map and refresh map will image
   */
  forceUpdateMap() {
    console.log("-----forceUpdateMap------")
    this.setState({ imageloaded: true });
  }

  /**
   * This method will fit all markers point into single screen 
   */
  fitAllMarkers() {
    const temMark = this.state.MARKERS;
    console.log( "------fitAllMarkers------")
    this.setState({loading:false});
    if (this.mapRef == null) {
      console.log("map is null")
    } else {
      //option:1  
      console.log("temMark : " + JSON.stringify(temMark));
      this.mapRef.fitToCoordinates(temMark, {
        edgePadding: DEFAULT_PADDING,
        animated: false,
      });              
    }
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          (this.state.coords != null) ?
            <MapView
              ref={ref => { this.mapRef = ref; }}
              style={styles.map}
              onLayout={() => this.fitAllMarkers()}>

              {/*used to drae line on rout point of locations*/}
              < MapView.Polyline
                coordinates={this.state.coords}
                strokeWidth={2}
              />

              {/*start point marker*/}
              <MapView.Marker
                key={1}
                coordinate={this.state.startMarker}
              />

              {/*end point marker*/}
              <MapView.Marker
                key={2}
                coordinate={this.state.destMarker}
              >                
              </MapView.Marker>
            </MapView> : null
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';
const origin = { latitude: 23.053150, longitude: 72.517100 };
const destination = { latitude: 23.053177, longitude: 72.517365 };
<MapView>
 <MapViewDirections
                    origin={origin}
                    destination={destination}
                    apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
                    strokeWidth={3}
                    strokeColor="rgb(0,139,241)" />
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use another library like : https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazyfox-map-direction

i used this lib on my last project, and it's really awesome, and its work on react-js and react-native.

Comment: Please provide more details in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling debugging mode on android. Seems like debugging mode affects it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Google API is okay and you have all rights to consume map view direction from Google.

A tip for anyone. React Native Maps renders successfully in functional components, but some features of this package may not work as expected in functional components. The MapViewDirections, in particular, did not work for me; it was impossible to get it working. I had to ever to using class-based components in my driver application, to continue supporting MapViewDirecctions.

This packages works well form me:
"react-native-maps": "^1.8.3",
"react-native-maps-directions": "^1.9.0",